# Why does Luke draw his blaster instead of his lightsaber to deal with an apparent threat?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

For almost 4 years after his training in the ways of the Force with Master Obi-Wan Kenobi, Luke Skywalker had kept with him the lightsaber that once belonged to his father; then, Luke first meets Yoda in the swamps of Dagobah. While Luke was setting up a temporary camp, the sudden, unexpected appearance of a small creature caused him to draw his blaster.

I ask: why was Luke, after having directly experienced/felt the power of the Force, more likely to reach for his blaster than his lightsaber to deal with an apparent threat?

[image: Still picture from Star Wars The Empire Strikes Back]

Comment: He's been using a blaster a lot longer than a lightsaber; don't underestimate the power of familiarity with a weapon.

Comment: Also the lightsaber is a melee weapon, a blaster has a longer range.

Comment: **STRANGE VOICE:** *Feel like what?*
[Luke jumps out of his skin.  Artoo screeches in terror.  The young warrior grabs for his lightsaber as he spins around, looking for the speaker.  Mysteriously standing right in front of Luke is a strange, bluish creature, not more than two feet tall.  The wizened little thing is dressed in rags.  It motions toward Luke's sword.]
**LUKE:** (looking at the creature) *Like we're being watched!*
**CREATURE:** *Away with your weapon!  I mean you no harm.*
[After some hesitation, Luke puts away his weapon, although he really 
doesn't understand why.]

Comment: In the [original script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html), ↑↑↑ Luke goes for his blaster earlier in the scene and then reholsters it. When Yoda turns up, he pulls **his lightsaber** but I'm guessing the aim was to save the reveal of the Jedi weapon for later in the film.

Comment: Nothing helpful in the junior novel "*“Feel like what?” a strange, croaking voice interrupted. Luke’s blaster flashed from its holster and he was suddenly aiming at a short, squat alien who sat on a nearby stump. “Like we’re being watched!” Luke finished."* or the trilogy novel "*That wasn’t Artoo’s voice! Luke leaped up, grabbed his pistol, then spun around, peering into the gloom to try to find the source of those words.*"

Comment: The new canon novelisation is even less use. It retcons the events of the film; "*You leap to your feet and spin at the same time, hands raised in self-defense. Half a meter from you sits one of the strangest creatures you have ever seen. He’s bluish-green, with long ears and bulging eyes. Your hand creeps slowly toward your lightsaber. “Who are you?” you demand.*

Comment: In the radio play, they explain it by having Yoda out of range of the lightsaber **YODA:** *Feel like what, stranger?* **LUKE:** *Like we're being watched! Don't you move, shorty, or I'll blow you right out of that tree!*

Comment: Lots of lightsaber stuff was removed from these scenes "**YODA:** *That would matter not were the Force flowing through you. Higher you’d jump! Faster you’d move! Open yourself to the Force you must.* **Luke**: [grabs his laser sword from the mud, ignites it and jumps up.] **LUKE**: *I’m open to it now! I feel it. Come on, you little flying bastards!* [As he moves toward the hovering balls with a poised saber and ferocious look, they draw away, retreating to the area around Yoda’s head.] **YODA**: *No, no. This will not do. Anger is what you feel.* **LUKE**: *But I can feel the Force flowing!*

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As [originally scripted](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html), Luke *did* pull out his lightsaber.

> *Nervously, he looks around at the foreboding jungle.*
>
> **Luke:** Still... there's something familiar about this place. I feel like... I don't know...
>
> **Strange Voice:** Feel like what?
>
> *Luke jumps out of his skin. Artoo screeches in terror. **The young warrior grabs for his lightsaber as he spins around, looking for the speaker.** Mysteriously standing right in front of Luke is a strange, bluish creature, not more than two feet tall. The wizened little thing is dressed in rags. It motions toward Luke's sword.*
>
> **Luke:** *(looking at the creature)* Like we're being watched!
>
> **Creature:** Away with your weapon! I mean you no harm.

So, my guess is this got changed as they were filming it for out-of-universe reasons rather than in-universe ones. One reason might be framing around the Yoda puppet: in order to get Luke, R2, and Yoda in that image you posted, Luke has to be squatting. If he pulled out a sword from that position, it'd look ridiculous.

Another possible answer is they were concerned that the blue lightsaber effect would disappear into the blue background of Dagobah. This is famously why Luke's lightsaber color was changed to green in *Return of the Jedi*, so it could be visible in the outdoor shots aboard Jabba's skiff.

Comment: Nice!  I can think of another out-of-universe reason to make this switch.  As I understand it, they were still using physical props for the lightsaber blades in *Empire* (just not reflective-coated like they were in the first movie), partly to make sure the "blade" was rotoscoped into the correct place.  It would be hard for Hamill to swing a 1m dowel from his waist to in front of him without hitting something, and switching from the hilt prop to the dowel prop mid-scene would likely result in a disconcerting jump like was seen in the previous movie when Obi-wan turned his off.

Comment: Yoda's speech also got more yodatastic between scripting and shooting: the scripted "away with your weapon" is merely a little archaic, whereas the film film has "away put your weapon"

Comment: "Bluish"? Now don't tell me Yoda was supposed to be blue.

Comment: I thought the blue-to-green change was because they wanted to explicitly acknowledge that he lost his original lightsaber at the end of ESB, and a simple change of the handle prop wasn't obvious enough.  I find it hard to believe that a blue lightsaber would be hard to see in a blue swamp - it's pretty bright.  And Jabba's skiff was mostly outdoor desert shots, I'd think either blue or green would show equally well against orange sand.

Comment: A superb answer.  Building on the key second-last paragraph here.  Don't forget, when you film a movie, shoot a scene, you "do what you want".  They may have tried a few different things and "just liked" that.  One aesthetic point: **when someone pulls out a lightsaber, it is A BIG MOMENT, it takes over the whole scene and is really dramatic.** This scene is all about the surprise of the audience seeing the amazing Yoda for the first time. (Remember that!) continuing...

Comment: ... it would be absolutely impossible to "know the answer" to this question unless one literally had Mr Lucas to talk to (and, indeed, he remembered every detail of his own thinking and others during the shooting of that scene) but for me, it really makes sense to low-key the weapon since that moment is about something else.  one more point, don't forget that **later, Yoda 'discovers' the lightsaber and it becomes a talking point**, that would be blown if the lightsaber was revealed at this point.

Comment: If blue was hard to see in Dagobah, why make the Force Ghosts blue?

Comment: @MaxD the puppeteer who performed Yoda, Frank Oz, was famous for performing two blue puppets on *Sesame Street*, Grover and Cookie Monster.

Comment: Apart from the visual, the light saber usually comes with sound, both which will destroy the mood of the scene.

Comment: @MaxD Funny, he doesn't *look* Bluish.

Comment: Thank you TenthJustice for your answer. Definitively Luke did pull out his lightsaber. I strongly believe that he had good skills with the lightsaber before meeting Yoda, to the extent that Vader (the former wielder) was impressed by that in Bespin. Luke could still practice the ways of the Force -even without Obi-Wan- by remembering an applying Kenobi's brief teachings.

Comment: "in order to get Luke, R2, and Yoda in that image you posted, Luke has to be squatting" - actually, it looks more like he's kneeling rather than squatting. With that said, though, there seems to be ample space above Luke's head in that image; quite possibly still enough even if he were standing.

Answer (score 38):

During *Empire*, Luke simply seems to be more comfortable with a blaster than with his lightsaber. He also draws it earlier on Dagobah when R2 has been pulled underwater and later when sneaking around Cloud City.

He was already able to use a blaster by the time of *A New Hope* (see [this comprehensive answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/163134/25746) on another question) and he's received no formal lightsaber training since Obi-Wan's death.

With that in mind, it makes sense that he would instinctively reach for his preferred weapon when already tense and surprised by Yoda, regardless of any tactical considerations.

Comment: Not only has he "received no formal lightsaber training since Obi-Wan's death", but that training only lasted a few hours.

Comment: I agree that at that point, Luke has had very little lightsaber training, so using a blaster seems perfectly reasonable, if not expected.  However, by the time Luke leaves Dagobah, he's *still* had very little lightsaber training (at least what was shown to film audiences)...

Comment: I know that if I had some attunement to this 'force' and was given a saber... that thing would be out and on pretty much every waking moment. Yoda's training would have to start with 'fixing' all of the bad habits I'd taught myself at that point.... argh, take this you pirate, arrrrrrrr "cuts off tree limb"

Comment: @jamesdlin: Also consider what Luke knows about the outcomes of lightsaber battles at that point.  (1) Here is the weapon your dad had when he was killed.  (2) The Jedi used them, and now most of them are dead.  (3) He watches Obi-Wan die while using one.  Not exactly inspiring.

Answer (score 16):

### Blasters are more recognizable

Possibly debatable, since he has no idea what the residents of Dagobah might be familiar with, but with the Jedi being largely unknown, a combatant doesn't immediately know the threat of a lightsaber, particularly if it's not ignited, but they know the threat of a gun, so they're more likely to back off.

Comment: I dunno about that argument; a dumb animal is much more likely to back off from a bright glowy buzzing thing being waved in their face than a little hunk of metal.  ([Appropriate story-id reference](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/247213/101407))

Comment: @DavidW Luke only draws a weapon after hearing someone speak, so he's immediately aware that he's dealing with an intelligent being and not a dumb animal.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is because a lightsaber though very powerful, does not have nearly as much range as a blaster and if the intruder was far away the lightsaber wouldn't really be able to take it out if far enough.

Comment: But as a Jedi he's not supposed to attack people and the lightsaber is a better defensive weapon, so tactical considerations aren't likely to be the reason.  This seems quite speculative; can you provide any evidence that he _intentionally_ chose the blaster?

Comment: So even if the Jedi is about to die, then he can still not pull out and attack?

Comment: @DavidW At this point in the movies he's had relatively limited jedi training and likely doesn't know or understand the jedi philosophy against aggression

Comment: that is tru tho

Comment: @DavidW He learned that part later in his training with Yoda. Sorry, but his precognition is nowhere near that level at the time.